# Spock - @Subject annotation and util | helper class that's being tested

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

I got a question regarding convention of tests in Spock.

Let us say we got **A** class to test, which is util class with static methods.
Classic way to test it, would be **A**.method() in each test method.

However, in Spock we got `@Subject` annotation (and also Groovy let us do that, even if said class has private constructor) and I began wondering.

```
@Subject util = new A()
```

And later in tests we would call the methods by `util.method()`.

By doing that, we would achieve cleaner test. Instantly we see what's being tested. In most IDEs it would be highlighted and so. `@Subject` is very verbose annotation.

Do you see any cons of doing tests such a way? Or there is any better way to clealny test util classes in Spock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see an advantage of having verbose `@Subject`, but instantiating utility class can cause much more confusion.

There is check it IntelliJ about instantiation of utility class:

> Reports any new expressions which instantiate utility classes. Utility classes have all fields and methods declared static, and their presence may indicate a lack of object-oriented design. Instantiation of such classes most likely indicates **programmer error**.

- It's unnatural and might be considered as programming mistake by other developers
- Disobeying `private` keyword is bad practice
- Sonar, CodeNarc and IntelliJ will most definitely complain

I would go with classic approach or avoiding utility classes at all. It's all about convention though.